# Compiling Pig Bank UDFs error

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Buildfile: C:\my\work\PigBank\contrib\piggybank\java\build.xml

```
init:

compile:
     [echo]  *** Compiling Pig UDFs ***
    [javac] Compiling 159 source files to C:\my\work\PigBank\contrib\piggybank\java\build\classes
    [javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
    [javac] C:\my\work\PigBank\contrib\piggybank\java\src\main\java\org\apache\pig\piggybank\evaluation\IsInt.j
    [javac]  * Note this function checks for Integer range 鈭?,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.
    [javac]                                                 ^
    [javac] 1 error
    [javac] 1 warning

BUILD FAILED
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure run ant on base directory
2. Then open:                  `PigBank\contrib\piggybank\java\src\main\java\org\apache\pig\piggybank\evaluation\IsInt.java` and edit line 31:

   ```
   29 /**
   30 * This UDF is used to check whether the String input is an Integer.
   31 * Note this function checks for Integer range −2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647.
   32 * If range is not important, use IsNumeric instead if you would like to check if     a String 33 is numeric. 
   34 * Also IsNumeric performs slightly better compared to this function.
   35 */
   ```

   1. Just remove unprintable character about on column 48 and save file.
   2. Run ant command again.